# Start php program with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to start a PHP program in an overlay fancybox window. The fancybox window flashes, but won't come into focus. Can I start PHP program through fancybox?

Here is code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.php-overlay").fancybox(
    {
        'width' : 600,
        'height' : 500,
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'scrolling' : 'yes',
        'hideOnContentClick' : false,
        'href' : 'http://example.com'
    });
}); 

$('#hiddenclicker').trigger('click');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't come into focus" exactly? Also, have you tried this on a real link and clicked it? I'm not sure whether that's the canonical way to open a fancybox programmatically.

Comment: Has this question been answered? If not; why not?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you trigger

$('a.php-overlay').trigger('click')

?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be trying to do is this:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="php-overlay" href="http://example.com">Open example.com in FancyBox</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("a.php-overlay").fancybox(
    'width' : 600,
    'height' : 500,
    'type': 'iframe'        
});
```

Fancybox will automatically attach an `onClick` event listener for you.